# Netbeans IDE remote development on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, software-development, ide

I tried to set up remote development with Netbeans IDE 7.3 Beta 2 so that I could build on my Raspberry Pi from my Win 7 laptop. I followed the pretty straightforward instructions [here](http://think-bowl.com/raspberry-pi/setup-a-project-in-netbeans-for-programming-on-the-raspberry-pi/), but unlike what is shown, Netbeans would not automatically recognize the GNU toolchain on the RPi.

I tried logging in as root (still had the same problem), and I also tried to manually add the toolchain to Netbeans. I was able to locate the toolchain executables (gcc, g++, gdb, etc.) but it seems that Netbeans is unable to access them, because it marks them as invalid.

My RPi is running Raspbian.

Comment: Don't use beta versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial you posted. The poster says that he is using version 7.2.1 of Netbeans. Have you tried using his version?

Sometimes a small change between versions will break something. Give version 7.2.1 a shot..

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. The author of the tutorial gave me the same advice.

Comment: The stable 7.3 works fine, for anyone who sees this later.